# Intellij using 80 to 90% of cpu

Tags: intellij-idea, indexing, cpu

Since yesterday my Inellij 14.1.3 has been acting up and making my macbook fly. It is doing nothing and using 80% of CPU.

Even after shutting down the macbook and re opening Intellij.

It looks like it is indexing 'a lot'. Everytime I wand to search for something it takes ages. 
My guess is some file have been corrupted and intellij is trying to index for ever.

Is there a way to fix this by deleting some temp files?

Comment: What happens if you invalidate caches? See `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` then click on the `Invalidate` button.

Comment: it fixes the issue, thanks didn't know about that option. (it was not showing up in my File menu,I had to go in the settings and put a short cut for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should invalidate caches.

See `File > Invalidate Caches / Restart` then click on the `Invalidate` button